# Symfony ManyToOne Form add, delete in DB

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have entity developer and comment and relationship Many comment to One developer. And I need form when I see all comment for developer and edit - add, delete in DB . What are the solutions to this problem

entity Comment:

```
class Comments
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Developer", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="talent_id", nullable = true, referencedColumnName="id")
     * */
    protected $talent;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="added_by", type="string", length=10, nullable=true)
     */
    private $added_by;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="comment", type="string", length=10, nullable=true)
     */
    private $comment;
```

entity Developer:

```
class Developer extends CustomUser
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /////
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comments", mappedBy="talent",  cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $comments;
```

Maybe need form in form but how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for field type [collection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html).

Example [usage of collection type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Comments
{
....
/**
*
*@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Developer", inversedBy="developer_to_comments")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="developer_to_comments_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
*
*/
private $comments_to_developer;
...
}
```

And class Developer

```
class Developer extends CustomUser
{
....
/**
*
* @var ArrayCollection
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comments", mappedBy="comments_to_developer", cascade={"remove"})
*/
private $developer_to_comments;

public function __construct()
{
  $this->developer_to_comments = new ArrayCollection();
}
....
}
```

And don't forget `use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection`